# SQL calculating sum based on another column

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following data in it:

```
Account number     Amount
13                 40
34                 30
14                 30
13                 60
14                 10
```

I would like to know how I can write a query to return the following results

```
Account number     Total amount
13                 100
14                 40
34                 30
```

The query should calculate the sum of all of the amounts in the amount column that share the same account number.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
select
    [Account Number],
    sum(Amount) Amount
from
    YourTable
Group by [Account Number]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Group By` + `SUM`

```
SELECT [Account number],
       SUM(Amount) As [Total Amount]
FROM dbo.Table1
GROUP BY [Account Number]
ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/374d6/4/0)

Comment: Thanks heaps for that!